# NHibernate Batching for Sybase

Tags: nhibernate

When setting the ado.batch_size property on the nhibernate configuration it is ignored.
If I debug the session it shows the batch size as 1 even though I set it to 25.

Does NHibernate 3.3.3 support batching for Sybase Anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No batching is only supported for the SQL Server Client and Oracle Client.
The Sybase driver uses the NonBatchingBatcher which means no batching.

**Extended Driver to use batching**
I've created a Batcher for NHibernate http://pastebin.com/gbPs6w4a

**Sample configuration**
The key line is db.Driver

```
Configuration.DataBaseIntegration(
            db =>
            {
                db.ConnectionString = "Some Connection String"
                db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.None;
                db.Driver<SybaseSQLAnywhereDotNet4WithBatcherDriver>();
                db.Dialect<SybaseSQLAnywhere12Dialect>();
                db.BatchSize = 25;
                db.LogSqlInConsole = showSqlInConsoleWindow;
                db.LogFormattedSql = showSqlInConsoleWindow;
            });
```